# Selectively configuring Apache 2 mod_headers for Google Chrome Frame

Tags: apache, apache2, apache-config, google-chrome-frame

I am currently evaluating Google Chrome Frame and so far i'm happy with it, but what i'd like to do is selectively use it for certain sections of my website.

Some sections require ActiveX so need to be viewed in native IE, whereas others benefit greatly, and may end up requiring, Chrome Frame.

I've currently got the following configured in my apache httpd.conf file -

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch chromeframe gcf
        Header append X-UA-Compatible "chrome=1" env=gcf
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

This causes anything coming in via Apache to get the chrome frame stuff added to the headers.

What I need is to make this only happen when a user visits particular URL's / particular pages, which i'm currently controlling via RewriteRules.

Could anybody explain how I would go about this, as my understanding of the Apache config files isn't brilliant.

Thanks.